# How to enable/disable the mousemove function when entering leaving a contained element (using mouseenter & mouseleave)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave

So right now I'm currently making a mousemove funtion that has a div following my cursor as I move around the screen. I want to keep that element within the "header" block so right now I just have it disappear with css and a mouseleave function whenever my cursor leaves the header element.

What I want to do, is as I leave the header element, the positioning of the div to reset into its original place from page load. Here's a snippet of my js edited for clarity:

```js
$( ".homehero" ).mouseleave(function() {
    // Not sure how to change this function here to turn off:
    /* $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
           $('.case-study #scene').offset({
               left: e.pageX + 70,
               top: e.pageY + 70
           });
        });  */
    $( "#scene" ).addClass( "hide-hero" ); // currently just hiding it 
});
$( ".homehero" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.case-study #scene').offset({
            left: e.pageX + 70,
            top: e.pageY + 70
        });
    });
    $( "#scene" ).removeClass( "hide-hero" ); // currently just showing it again on mouseenter
});
```

Note, `#scene` is the div that is inside of the header `.homehero` element. Below is a screencapture of what I'm currently doing now.

[image: Screen capture of mousemove]

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: Call [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and reset the position.

Comment: It would help to also at least see the HTML and CSS here, if not an MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use jQuery's [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method which lets you actually remove the listener you would need to keep a reference to that function in order for off() to remove just that listener. Otherwise you would have to call `.off("mousemove")`. When called without a function reference it will remove *all* listeners. This could cause problems if some other code needs to add the same event.

Instead you can setup the mousemove like the others. And then use a flag that you set in mouseenter and unset in mouseleave. Test for that flag in your mousemove callback, leaving immediately if it tests as false

```
var enableMove = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if(!enableMove) return;

  $('.case-study #scene').offset({
    left: e.pageX + 70,
    top: e.pageY + 70
  });
});

$( ".homehero" ).mouseleave(function() {
  enableMove = false;
  $( "#scene" ).addClass( "hide-hero" );
});

$( ".homehero" ).mouseenter(function() {
  enableMove = false;
  $( "#scene" ).removeClass( "hide-hero" ); 
});
```

As for the positioning issue you could just save the element's coordinates on mouseenter and use that saved data to set the coordinates on exit. You can use jQuery's [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data) method to save the information on the element itself and retrieve it later.

```
//in mouseenter
var $element = $('.case-study #scene');
$element.data("originalCoordinates",$element.offset());

//in mouseleave
var $element = $('.case-study #scene');
$element.offset( $element.data("originalCoordinates") );
```

Comment: hmm, I tried this snippet except removing the add/remove classes lines since that wouldn't be needed in the new solution, then on mouseenter changing the `enableMove` to true as I wanted the the `mousemove` effect to work within the `.homehero` block the `#scene` block lives within.  

The issue I ran into is that the data element doesn't predictably re-set the `#scene` block back into its original position; if i move my cursor in a certain way on `mouseleave`, it potentially resets its position somewhere else on the page outside of `.homehero`

Comment: here's an example of the result: https://media.giphy.com/media/cY5oZUNhQp6Lneuxrv/giphy.mp4

Comment: @Alex Are you changing the element's css position, ie to absolute? If so then you don't need to save the coordinates just set the position back to the original "static" and set both left, top to 0

Comment: Yes! so I'm using a combo of flexbox and absolute positioning, but what I did was take your snippet, removed the data elements as suggested out of the mouseenter/leave, and put back in the add/remove classes. Only now, I add and remove a class that overrides the original positioning and setting the top, left, right, and bottom at 0. 

    .hero-reset {
 left: 0!important;
 right: 0!important;
 top: 0!important;
 bottom: 0 !important;
 align-self: center!important;
 margin: auto!important;
    }

So far, that seems to have done the trick. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
$('selector')
        .mouseleave(function() {
      $('targetSelector').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 250 );
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('targetSelector').animate({ 'margin-left': '150px' }, 
250 );
  });
```